# How do I get the return type of a delegate type through reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm doing reflection-heavy work for a personal project, and I'd need to access the return type of a delegate through its `Type` object. This is a little meta, so here's an example.

```
Type type = typeof(Func<Foo, Bar, Baz>);
// ????
// Use reflection to come to the following expected result
Type result = typeof(Baz);
```

How can I do that?

I won't have any instance of that type to cast into `Delegate`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

One way would be to get a `MethodInfo` representing the delegate-type's `Invoke` method, and then retrieve the method's return type.

```
var result = type.GetMethod("Invoke").ReturnType;
```